# Trying to calculate percent complete for all tasks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of tasks in column B (all with different names). In column F I write `done` if the task has been completed or leave it blank if it has not. I want to calculate the percent of completed tasks but can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use COUNTIF to get the number of tasks that you have marked as done and COUNTA all to get the total number of tasks. The percent complete will equal the result of the COUNTIF count divided by the COUNTA count.

Answer (score 1):

@chuff has answered but to be a little more specific:

[image: SU605014 example]

Note that in the example the columns are labelled (though mostly blank!) and since, for simplicity, the formula addresses entire columns provision is required to exclude counting `B1` when this has text in it because COUNTA counts any and all text entries.